# Use previous entry as default in attribute table

Tags: attribute-table, qgis-2, default-value

I have a vector layer that I add observations to by identifying features in georeferenced rasters (images). One of the attributes I want to assign to the feature is the image name (which I currently read from the layers tab and enter manually into the attributes table). Ideally, I would like for this to be read automatically, but at least I would like to only have to enter this once, for the first observation from a newly opened image, and for this value to be the default for new points selected. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE Martin. Could you tell us, which software you're using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using QGIS 2.18, on a PC running Windows in 64-bit mode.

Comment: A hapazard workaround would be to enter those parts of the images names which are always the same into `texteditor`-field belonging to the specific column in the `fields`-tab of the layers properties.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set option to reuse last entered values. To do that:

1. Open Settings menu -> Options...
2. Open Digitizing tab
3. In "Feature creation" group check "Reuse last entered attribute
   values"

Comment: If the answer was helpful, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: This definitely does the trick. I wish there were a way to do this only for selected fields, because certain fields (like street names, in the project I'm working on) make sense to reuse, but other fields I'd like to maintain the default values I set.

Comment: Sorry to jump on this question. But I had the same question and feel there should be an Expression for this..but I can't find it. In QFIELD there's an option for this and I'm sure they just use an expression. Probably there's a way to provide this layer specific via Layer properties > Attribute form >Defaults > [specific expression, we don't know yet]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in QField since one of the last updates i guess.
but only regarding check boxes
when i check a box the next added feature will automatically show the box as checked. Funny thing though is that it doesnt take over the value. It seems to be a graphical issue.
Any ideas how to solve this?